# what are the commands that will create this git graph

Tags: git, git-log

hello guys I am new to git and I am working on a project where I need to respect this graph I just want to know what can I do to get this git graph what are the commands and with explanation please

All I know that every vertex is a commit all the labels are branch names
I don't know where to start like do I need to create all branches before or what it's not clear at all

[image: git graph]

Comment: What exactly do you want? what branches do you have now?

Comment: Start with `git log --graph --oneline --decorate` (the function of each command-line argument is self-evident). If you need something graphical, there are lots of GUI that will do this (like `gitk`).

Comment: i want the exact commands that will creat this graph , i know that i can use gitk to print a graph but i want this exact graph

Comment: I think the confusion is that you're asking "what are the commands that will create this graph?", but you don't meant that (your goal is not to draw a picture).  You are asking "what sequence of git commands will reproduce the git history represented by this picture?"

Comment: ...of course, the very first thing we will ask you is, "what have you tried so far?"

Comment: yes you got it right ! all i did is like doing three 'git commit'' comands to creat the commits but i dont know how to get this with branch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git init                                 # initialize a git repo
git commit --allow-empty -m foo          # create a commit with message "foo"
git checkout -b feature1                 # create and check out a branch named "feature1" from the current commit
git commit --allow-empty -m bar          # create a commit with message "bar"
git checkout -b feature2                 # create and check out a branch named "feature2" from the current commit
git commit --allow-empty -m baz          # create a commit with message "baz"
git checkout -b feature3                 # create and check out a branch named "feature3" from the current commit
git commit --allow-empty -m qux          # create a commit with message "qux"
git checkout master                      # check out branch "master"
git commit --allow-empty -m toto         # create a commit with message "toto"
git merge -m 'merge feature 1' feature1  # merge feature1 with message "merge feature 1"
git merge -m 'merge feature 2' feature2  # merge feature2 with message "merge feature 2"
git merge -m 'merge feature 3' feature3  # merge feature3 with message "merge feature 3"
```

[image: Graph]